# How do I play sound on clicking a list view item?

Tags: android

I'm very new to Java and Android development and can't seem to find what I'm after. I have a basic list set up, each list item has a different title, description and icon. What I'd like is when a list item is clicked, a sound is played, this sound would be different for each list item.

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class TestingList extends ListActivity {

    private static final String ICON_KEY = "icon";
    private static final String TITLE_KEY = "title";
    private static final String DETAIL_KEY = "detail";

    private static final int[] ICONS = new int[] { R.drawable.lista,
                    R.drawable.listb, R.drawable.listc, R.drawable.listd };
    private static final String[] TITLES = new String[] { "List 1", "List 2",
                    "List 3", "List 4" };
    private static final String[] DETAILS = new String[] {
                    "List 1 description",
                    "List 2 description",
                    "List 3 description",
                    "List 4 description" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            List<Map<String, Object>> rows = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < ICONS.length; i++) {
                    rows.add(createListItemMap(ICONS[i], TITLES[i],
                                    DETAILS[i]));
            }

            String[] fromKeys = new String[] { ICON_KEY, TITLE_KEY, DETAIL_KEY };
            int[] toIds = new int[] { R.id.icon, R.id.text1, R.id.text2 };
            setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, rows,
                            R.layout.icon_detail_list_item, fromKeys, toIds));
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> createListItemMap(int icon,
                    CharSequence title, CharSequence detail) {
            Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            row.put(ICON_KEY, icon);
            row.put(TITLE_KEY, title);
            row.put(DETAIL_KEY, detail);
            return row;
    }

    public static void showView(Context c) {
          c.startActivity(new Intent(c, TestingList.class));
    }
}
```

Help much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The Android docs describe a variety of ways to play [audio](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

You are already half way the only thing you have to add is as follows.

1.You need to chose where to put your audio files you want to play ,
 you have two option to embed your audio file in the application as 
 a resource or to put audio files on external file storage.

2.Override onListItemClick event as shown below

```
    @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


            //Place your code here


   }
```

3.Option one  create raw folder in your resource directory and import all your audio to this directory, and you will get the as a resource like "R.raw.audio1" . and place this code in the event above.

```
       MediaPlayer  mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio1);
       mPlayer .start();
```

4.Option two create folder on your external storage and put your audio files and you will get your audio file by path using environment variable.

```
    File externalStorage= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path=externalStorage.getAbsolutePath() + "/your_audio_directory/adio1.mp3";
     MediaPlayer   mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
     mPlayer .setDataSource(path);
     mPlayer .prepare();
     mPlayer .start();
```

1. Enjoy  , and don't forget to click answered thanks